# How to use pipeline input in a foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

Trying to run a command in a `foreach` loop that contains different search locations, e.g.:

```psh
$ous ='ou=Staff,dc=example,dc=local', 'ou=Managers,dc=example,dc=local'

$colItems = $ous | ForEach { Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Example,dc=example,dc=local" -Properties whenCreated | select -Property Enabled,Name,SamAccountName,whenCreated }
```

I want to replace the OU in the search query each time

```
"ou=Example,dc=example,dc=local"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a pipeline with a `ForEach-Object` loop, you must use the current object variable (`$_`) to refer to the current object from the pipeline. Change this:

```psh
$ous | ForEach { Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Example,dc=example,dc=local" -Properties ... }
```

into this:

```psh
$ous | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -Properties ... }
```

See [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was my answer.

```
$colItems = ForEach ($ou in $ous) { Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties whenCreated | select -Property Enabled,Name,SamAccountName,whenCreated }
```

Comment: please use `foreach($ou in $ous)` (without the uppercase letters) - lessens confusion between the `foreach` loop construct and the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet alias